# Rails validate parameter combinations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a search form with many fields. Each field is a parameter for searching a very large database. These parameters are passed to a search object. Some combinations of parameters are valid, others are not (they put too heavy a load on the system). What is the best way to write validations for combinations of parameters? For example: You should be able to search by name and one other field, but not name alone. In some cases if you enter a value in one field, you cannot enter a value in others

Currently I have something like this in my search class.

```
SEARCHABLE_ATTRIBUTES = [:name, :city, :state, :phone, :invoice_number, :payment_amount, :payment_date, :current_balance]

validate: valid_combinations

def valid_combinations
  unless name.present? && (SEARCHABLE_ATTRIBUTES - [:name, :invoice_number]).select{|sa| send(sa).present?}.any?
    errors.add(:name, "can't be given alone.")
  end
  if name.present? && invoice_number.present?
    errors.add(:invoice_number, "can't be searched with name")
  end
end
```

My valid search param restrictions get more complex than this, but this is just an example. Is there a better way to do this? I'd like to avoid one big valid_combinations method.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a condition to the validation and it will run only if that condition returns true.

So you could create separated validation methods and use them like this:

```
validate :at_least_another_column, if: Proc.new{|record| record.name }
```

Or, if you create a condition method named `name_present` you could code it like this:

```
validate :at_least_another_column, if: :name_present
```

To substitute your second condition you could use`:absence` and `:message` options. Looking like this:

```
validates :invoice_number, absence: true, if: :name_present , message: "can't be searched with name"
```

As you can see the code becomes much cleaner and understandable when using separated validations. But depending on how complex your conditions may be, it could be easier to create a giant validator method

There's a lot more about validations [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validation-helpers)